# Медленно работает скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery, производительность

Народ, я тут первую "программку" накалякал, вроде работает, но медленно! Вот хотел провести работу над ошибками, надеюсь поможете! Посмотрите, что я не так как надо написал?!
Прошу сильно не ругать, заранее спасибо!

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){

//подгружаем доп модуль в конструктор
var cns_1 = $('#cns_1'); cns_1.hide();
$('#select2').change(function(){
    var selected = $("#select2 option:selected").val();
    if (selected == 'безпружинный'){ 
cns_1.show(); }else{ cns_1.hide();}
});

//отправляем данные в обработчик
$('#form').change(function(){ //отправляем данные из конструктора
var m_method=$(this).attr('method'); //берем из формы метод передачи данных
var m_action=$(this).attr('action'); //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
var m_data=$(this).serialize(); //получаем данные, введенные пользователем в формате input1=value1&input2=value2...,

$('#foo').addClass('active'); //затемняем экран
$('#preloader').addClass('active'); //затемняем экран
$('.calc_ch').prop('disabled', true);

    $.ajax    ({
        type    : m_method,
        url : m_action,
        data    : m_data,
        cache   : false,
        async   : true,
        success : function(result){
              setTimeout ("$('#foo').removeClass('active');", 500);
              setTimeout ("$('#preloader').removeClass('active');", 500);
                  setTimeout ("$('.calc_ch').prop('disabled', false);", 500);
              $('#visual').html(result).show("slow"); 
            }
            });

    $.ajax    ({
        type    : m_method,
        url : '/php/constructor/error.php',
            data    : m_data,
            cache   : false,
        async   : true,
        success : function(html){             
             $("#errors").html(html);            
              }
    });

});

$('#mail_send').live('click', function() { //отправляем данные из формы заказа
var m_method=$(this).attr('method'); //берем из формы метод передачи данных
var m_data=$('#mail_form').serialize();

$('#foo').addClass('active'); //затемняем экран
$('#preloader').addClass('active'); //затемняем экран
$('.calc_ch').prop('disabled', true);

    $.ajax    ({
        type    : m_method,
        url : '/php/constructor/mail_send.php',
        data    : m_data,
        cache   : false,
        success : function(result){
              $('#errors').html(result);
              setTimeout ("$('#foo').removeClass('active');", 500);
              setTimeout ("$('#preloader').removeClass('active');", 500);
                  setTimeout ("$('.calc_ch').prop('disabled', false);", 500);
                  }
    });

return false; 
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Что значит "медленно"?

Comment: ну когда прикрутил аякс, обработка Php скприпта стала занимать больше времени, хотя может мне так кажется ))


и еще, хотел эффекты прилепить, чет не получается, пишу вот так:

$('#errors').html(result).show("drop",{},1000);

не срабатывает (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#select2').change(function(){
    var selected = $("#select2 option:selected").val();
    if (selected == 'безпружинный'){ cns_1.show(); }
    else{ cns_1.hide();}
});
```

Как вариант:

- Привыкайте использовать метод .on()
- Внутри использовать $(this)
- Если у Вас только .show() и .hide(), посмотрите в сторону .toggle()
- Про setTimeout уже сказали

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас приходят ответы от сервера медленно, это ещё не означает, что во всём виноват JQuery.

Попробуйте оптимизировать php, sql скрипты. Говорят, помогает.

Comment: все-таки вопрос звучал - помогите провести работу над ошибками, т.е. со стороны jquery все правильно написано?